# Not all toolbar items seem to work in ckeditor inline

Tags: ckeditor, inline

using ckeditor in inline mode not all items of the standard configuration show up, e.g. the align items. Align would make sense in inline mode I should think?

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here.
// For complete reference see:
// http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

// The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];

// Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
// not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

// Set the most common block elements.
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

// Simplify the dialog windows.
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Standard Preset while the [Bidi plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/search/plugins/bidi) is only available in the Full Preset. You either need to use the Full Preset or add this plugin to your preset (manually or through [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder)) - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_plugins.html.